# Can I have my iOS app automatically send an email?

Tags: ios, email

I would like my app to send an email to my email address from another one of my email addresses.  Basically I would like to program it such that it has the username and password for the sending address in the code so that it can compose and send an email without the user having to do anything.

To make it clearer, this would be to place an order that I would receive via email.  The user selects all the options they want in the app then once the order is confirmed the app will send all the details to me via email.

I could not find any information on this, even whether or not it's possible. Every time I tried to search I just came up with results about how to open the mail view in your app, which is not at all what I want.

I don't necessarily need all the code, even if you could point me in the direction of a tutorial or something it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an email on behalf of the user without presenting the standard email view.

However, there are a few services that you can use to accomplish your goal. Have a look at Mandrill or Mailgun.

Comment: I'm sure there are apps that automatically send the user email confirmations, would these type of services be needed for that?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not allowed by Apple.

Long answer: not allowed by Apple because this would allow programmers to send emails from a user's device without their knowledge or consent.

Comment: Aren't there apps that automatically send the user an email confirmation for, let's say, orders?  Or would something like that go through a website or third party service?

Comment: Yes, website or 3rd party.